# Calling Fortran from R: "Funny sized logical array"

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran

Here is a *funny* problem I am encountering with R and Fortran.

Consider the following Fortran subroutine:

```
! foo.f90
subroutine fun(n, x)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in) :: n
  logical, intent(in) :: x(n)
  integer :: i

  write(*,*) pack([(i, i=1, n)], x)

end subroutine fun
```

When compiled with `R CMD SHLIB foo.f90` and called in R with

```
dyn.load("foo.so")
x <- c(TRUE ,FALSE)
f <- .Fortran("fun", 2L, as.logical(x))
```

I get the error message:

```
Fortran runtime error: Funny sized logical array
```

When the same subroutine is called from a Fortran program,

```
! test.f90
program test
  implicit none
  logical :: x(2)

  x = [.true., .false.]
  call fun(2, x)

contains

  include "foo.f90"

end program test
```

no error occurs:

```
$ gfortran foo.f90 test.f90 -o test
$ ./test 
           1
```

**Potential culprit:** The Fortran compiler I am using for this example. I used GNU Fortran 9.2.1. I noticed the same problem with gfortran 8.3.0, but no errors with earlier versions 7.4.0, 6.5.0 and 5.5.0.
But why would the Fortran program `test.f90` with the same subroutine work here? (even when the same flags used by `R CMD SHLIB` are used to compile `foo.f90` and `test.f90`: `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fimplicit-none -fcheck=all -fbacktrace`).

This looked *funny* at the beginning, but after some time playing around with this problem, this is getting frustrating...

Thanks in advance for your help.

More details:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.1
```

Comment: Might this be related to R using (32 bit) integers for logical values?

Comment: One should use the same compiler version that was used as a reference when compiling your R distribution. Fortran ABI does differ between versions. That said, I am not sure how that would create a probem for your simple subroutine.

Comment: @RalfStubner gfortran uses the same.

Comment: FWIW, works for me with R 3.4.4 (from Ubuntu 18.04 repos), gfortran 10.0.0 built from gcc trunk.

Comment: The "Funny sized logical array" error message comes from the implementation of the pack intrinsic, when it checks the element length of the mask array. Before calling pack, try printing out the values of n and x, and see if there's something fishy there?

Comment: Also, run "ldd foo.so" and check that you have a) only one libgfortran.so that you link to, and b) that version is the version that corresponds to the version of gfortran you're using as well as the version that R is built against.

Comment: In your R code, you are using `2L`.  Is that a 64-bit long integer (in C parlance)?  The Fortran code is expecting a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your comments and suggestions, that was very helpful. As @janneb suggested, there was a discrepancy between the version of gfortran used to compile the code and the version R was built against. I ran the same code in a docker container with gfortran 9.2.1 and no error occurred.

Comment: @evets, an R constant like `2L` is an integer not a "long integer".  In R, unadorned constants like `2` (without a decimal point) are treated as floating point.

Comment: @King: Yes, it is. Note that the logical array in this case is not the array to be packed, but rather the mask array (which must be of type logical).